How do you clearly and concisely describe the union of a particular function's outputs for one of many functions?
I'm writing research and I've encountered quite a specific problem. The following are example sentences I came up with to try to explain a particular concept. Note that the following is analogous to the actual concept I'm trying to communicate which would require a ton more context:

A shopping list is a set $X$ that is constructed by selecting a recipe
for each desired dish and constructing $X$ such that $X$ only contains every
ingredient in every selected recipe.

Here is another formulation of the same example which is less algorithmic sounding:

A shopping list is a set only containing every ingredient $i$ where
$i$ is in a particular recipe for each desired dish.

Finally here is a more formal formulation:

A shopping list is a set only containing every ingredient $i \in g(x)$ for every desired dish $x$ where $g(x)$ is a particular recipe
of $x$.

I'm trying to imply that every dish is associated with multiple recipes (there are many ways to make a dish!) which can be interpreted as a function $f$ where $f(x)$ is a set of recipes for dish $x$. However, to create a shopping list we need to choose a subset of dishes and choose a recipe per dish which implies a function $g$ where $g(y)$ is the chosen recipe for chosen/desired dish $y$. There could exist many functions that map each desired dish $y$ to a recipe in $f(y)$. Each recipe is actually a set of ingredients, so we can effectively union every output $g(y)$ to create the shopping list (e.g. no need to write down tomatoes twice!). Note that in this example an ingredient in one recipe could be an ingredient in another recipe.
The first example I gave above explains it without much ambiguity. But "construct-" is repeated and perhaps the concept is simple enough to communicate without explaining a small algorithm.
The second example is short but ambiguous, am I really talking about selecting a recipe per dish and combining the selected recipe's ingredients? Could it be interpreted as a set of ingredients which is in every one of the particular recipes I'm talking about?
I'm unsure if the last example has sufficiently removed the aforementioned ambiguity. Something about it still seems unclear to me but I'm not exactly sure why.
I would be interested to know if there are any alternative ways to explain the concept that I may not have considered or any suggestions to improve conciseness and reduce ambiguity in these examples I gave.

How about “A shopping list is a set of the form $L = \cup_{r \in R} I(r)$, where $R$ is a set of recipes and $I : R \rightarrow 2^{\cal I}$ maps each recipe to the set of ingredients it requires”? Note though, that depending on your data model, you might want $L$ to be a multiset. I mean, suppose two of your recipes each call for a chicken.

@PaulTanenbaum that is a good suggestion which I would only slightly change to fit with the example. Perhaps something like this: A shopping list is a set $L=\cup_{i \in I}g(i)$ where $g(i)$ is a recipe for dish $i$ and $I$ only contains every desired dish. Does that make sense to you?

No, to me that’s unclear. For one thing, what is meant by the set  I? You specify its extension but not its intension.

@PaulTanenbaum What I'm trying to get across is that $I$ is the set of all dishes that the shopper wants to cook. From that article it seems an extensional definition would be a list of all sets that $I$ could be (every subset of the set of all dishes?). But perhaps I'm not understanding in this context. Could you expand on your point? Also, in the following example, is my definition of $I$ extentional or intentional? A shopping list is a set $L=\cup_{i \in I}g(i)$ where $g(i)$ is the set of ingredients of a recipe for dish $i$ and $I$ is the set of all dishes that the shopper wants to cook.

Ah, I had used $I$ for ingredients. Are you after something like “$L=\cup_{d\in D} I(d)$, where $D$ is the set of dishes one wants to prepare, and $I:D\rightarrow{\cal I}$ maps each dish to the ingredients it requires,” where $\cal I$ is the set of all conceivable ingredients?

I see where the confusion lies. So what I'm trying to get across is that there can be multiple recipes for the same dish (e.g. multiple methods for making lasagna) and one recipe for a dish could have ingredients that are different to another recipe of that dish (e.g. one lasagna recipe has oregano, another has celery etc.). Hence, different shopping lists may exist for the same set of dishes depending on the chosen recipes per dish.

Okay, so maybe $\cup_{d \in M} I(r(d))$, where the menu $M$ is the set of dishes you wish to prep are, $r:D\rightarrow R$ maps dishes to your preferred recipes for them, and $I:R\rightarrow\cal I$ maps recipes to the ingredients they require? (And my comment about multi sets still applies.)

If you post your last comment as an answer I will accept!

Try
$$
\bigcup_{d \in \cal M} I(r(d)),
$$
where $\cal M$ is your menu (the set of dishes you wish to prepare), $r:\cal D\rightarrow R$ maps dishes to your preferred recipe for each, and $I:\cal R\rightarrow I$ maps recipes to the sets of ingredients required for each.
